# How to look a 230V ,50 Hz AC power supply via oscilloscope from the switchboard?

Tags: ac, oscilloscope

I am from India. My household supply is 230V, 50 Hz. Now I want to observe the AC supply from the switch board using oscilloscope.Is it ok ? How to do it?(I mean just a resistor attenuator is sufficient?)What  precautions I need to follow? Does it really look like a sine wave?

Comment: As a general rule DO NOT PLUG THE OSCILLOSCOPE PROBE TO YOUR HOUSEHOLD SUPPLY. Sorry caps, but you'll probably trigger the switches.

Answer (score 1):

1. It really looks like a sine wave (because it is a sine wave.)
2. You would do better to find a wall wart that puts out AC than to try to put something together yourself.

An AC wallwart is nothing but a transformer.  It will lower the line voltage to something low enough for your oscilloscope to measure.

More importantly, **it keeps you away from high voltages.**

As a handy side effect, it prevents your oscilloscope from causing a short circuit (with associated flash, bang, and circuit breaker trip) when you accidentally connect the oscilloscope ground to the live wire of the outlet.